# who/whom as both subject and object in same context

Tags: parts-of-speech, subject-vs-object-pronouns

Which of the following is preferred, and why?:

1. I know many *who* are like you.
2. I know many *whom* are like you.

The pivotal word appears to function as an object and a subject, depending on the clause to which  it is considered in relation.

Comment: The pronoun is part of the relative clause, where it is functioning as subject, so "who" is correct

Comment: Incidentally, what makes you think that "who(m) is functioing as an object? An object of what?

Comment: @BillJ: I suppose the object of the sentence is "many who are like you", which might mean that the clause ought to be expressed with "whom" instead of "who", depending on how the grammar would be specified.

Comment: Yes, the verb "know" has the NP "many [who(m) are like you]" as its object. Within the NP "who(m) are like you" is a relative clause modifying "many", and the pronoun is subject of that relative clause, not object of "know", so it can only be subjective "who".

Comment: Do we similarly prefer "We pay respect to them *who* perished", for the same reasons?

Comment: Yes, the pronoun is subject of the relative clause "who perished".

Comment: However, we also use "We also respect them *whom* we fought", because in such case the pronoun has a different relation within the dependent clause?

Comment: Yes, in that example, the pronoun is object of "fought" in the relative clause.

Comment: (1) is OK, (2) is ungrammatical. _Whom_ can't be a subject.

Answer (score 0):

*Whom* is an object pronoun and *who* is not, so if a preposition precedes X, and X can either be *who* or *whom*, then it should be *whom*.

> I know many *who* are like you.

> Don't ask for *whom* the bell tolls.

[Reference][1]

If any doubt, always use *who* - no one will notice or care if you use *who*, but using *whom* incorrectly or unexpectedly can raise eyebrows.

[1]: [https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/grammar/relative_pronouns/index.html#:~:text=The%20most%20common%20relative%20pronouns,can%20function%20as%20relative%20pronouns.](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/grammar/relative_pronouns/index.html#:%7E:text=The%20most%20common%20relative%20pronouns,can%20function%20as%20relative%20pronouns.))

Answer (score 0):

Correct: 1. I know many **who** are like you. **Who** works here as the subject of the relative clause.

subject- , object- ,

subject- He, object- him,

I know the man. **He** came here last Sunday. I know the man **who** came here last Sunday. 'Who' joins two clauses together. 'Who' is the subject of the second clause. We use 'who' in the same way as 'he'.

This is Mr. Farukh. You met **him** last Sunday. This is Mr. Farukh **whom** you met last Sunday. 'Whom' joins two clauses together. 'Whom' is the object of the second clause. We use 'whom' in the same way as 'him'.

'Whom' is the object form of 'who'. We usually use **who**, not whom, as an object. In a very formal style 'whom' is used.

Who did you see? (= Whom did you see?- very formal) 'Whom/who' is the object and 'you' is the subject.